# Get accordion open closed status in mat table with accordion - Angular7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7, mat-table

I'm using mat-table with accordion, all I want is, whether the mat-row is expanded/closed in mat table

[Stackblitz-Mat-table with expandable rows](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yr45pl)

I want in such a way like `(opened)="panelOpened($event)" (closed)="panelClosed($event)"` in mat expansion panel. 
How the above can be achieved in mat table? If not, is there any other way to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you use mat-accordian in provided stackblitz ?

Comment: I haven't used exactly mat accordion, I have just used mat table with expandable rows, which is a similar to that of mat accordion/expansion

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yenyee-expandable-row?file=src/app/table-expandable-rows-example.ts)

1. Adding `(click)="toggleExpandableRow(element)"` on your row element
2. In `toggleExpandableRow(element)`, check the `this.expandedElement` is equal to clicked row `element`.
3. If `this.expandedElement` is **equal** to clicked row `element`(it means you click on the expanded row), assign `null` to the `this.expandedElement`(it will close the panel)
4. If `this.expandedElement` is **not equal** to clicked row `element`(it means you click on the other row), assign clicked row `element` to the `this.expandedElement`(it will open the panel)
5. Then, you can check if `this.expandedElement` is null or not:

   - if `this.expandedElement` is not null, it means clicked row is expanded, you can emit your opened event here
   - if `this.expandedElement` is null, it means no row is expanded, you can emit your closed event here

```html
<tr mat-row 
    *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;" 
    class="example-element-row"
    [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element" 
    (click)="toggleExpandableRow(element)">
</tr>
```

```js
expandedElement: PeriodicElement | null;

toggleExpandableRow(element: PeriodicElement | null) {
  const isClickedElementExpanded = this.expandedElement === element;
  this.expandedElement = isClickedElementExpanded ? null : element;
  if (this.expandedElement) {
    // if expandedElement is not null, it means clicked row is expanded
    this.panelOpened();
  } else {
    // if expandedElement is null, it means no row is expanded
    this.panelClosed();
  }
}

panelOpened() {
  console.log("panelOpened");
}

panelClosed() {
  console.log("panelClosed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you maintain a variable on which will keep track of your open, close status. In your dataSource array have a variable rowStatus false for each row initially:

```
[
  {'column1': 'data', 'column2': 'data', 'rowStatus': false},
  {'column1': 'data', 'column2': 'data', 'rowStatus': false},
  {'column1': 'data', 'column2': 'data', 'rowStatus': false},
]
```

In your .html, for column you can add click event:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="columnClicked(row)"></tr>
```

Now, the hack is to negate the rowStatus after clicking the column in .ts:

```
columnClicked(element) {
  element.rowStatus = !element.rowStatus
}
```

At any point of time, if the rowStatus is false then it is closed. else it is opened.
But, then this variable(rowStatus) is recommended to be in array object of your table column. So, each column will have a unique rowStatus variable and open, close of each column will be independent.
Hope I'm clear. It is very abstract and this must work for you. Just change your array of objects accordingly